# How to position textview to the bottom right corner of the button using linear layout

Tags: android

I am designing the login logout but stuck in designing. I want to put the text view to the right corner of the button using a linear layout. It must not change its view in landscape mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:context=".ForgotPassword">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.329" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendlink"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="send_link"
        android:text="SEND  LINK"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"       //here i need to manage that situation
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="90dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="or"
            android:textColor="#FD050000"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Login?"
            android:textColor="#071041"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

  </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Please help I expect that the text "or Logout" must be positioned at the bottom of the right corner of the "SEND LINK" button.**

Comment: Constraint layout is mainly for constructing the no hierarchy layouts. So please avoid using the linearlayout and relativelayouts in that if its not needed.

As you can see in my answer it can all be manged in single parant view only, which will make UI render faster.

Comment: I accept that but what if a user switches to landscape mode. I checked that and my view all got messed up.

Comment: That's what constraint layout here for.

Comment: can you please suggest me some samples of design so that I could understand constraint layout better. google link or any website

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 3):

Do like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/sendlink"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="send_link"
        android:text="SEND  LINK"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="or"
        android:textColor="#FD050000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sendlink"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="Login?"
        android:textColor="#071041"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sendlink"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sendlink"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendlink"
        android:onClick="send_link"
        android:layout_width="236dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="SEND  LINK"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="or Login?"
        android:textColor="#071041"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/sendlink"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sendlink">

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/login"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:onClick="login"
           android:text="or Login?"
           android:textColor="#071041"
           android:textSize="16sp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/sendlink"
       android:layout_width="236dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:onClick="send_link"
       android:text="SEND  LINK"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```